# Pandas - replace for loop for efficiency

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop, dataframe

I have a data frame (df)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'No': [123,234,345,456,567,678], 'text': ['60 ABC','1nHG','KL HG','21ABC','K 200','1g HG'], 'reference':['ABC','HG','FL','','200',''], 'result':['','','','','','']}, columns=['No', 'text', 'reference', 'result'])

    No    text reference result
0  123  60 ABC       ABC       
1  234    1nHG        HG       
2  345   KL HG        FL       
3  456   21ABC                 
4  567   K 200       200       
5  678   1g HG
```

and a list with elements

```
list
['ABC','HG','FL','200','CP1']
```

Now I have the following coding:

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows(): 

    for item in list:

        if row['text'].strip().endswith(item):

            if pd.isnull(row['reference']):
                df.at[idx, 'result'] = item

            elif pd.notnull(row['reference']) and row['reference'] != item:                
                df.at[idx, 'result'] = 'wrong item'

            if pd.isnull(row['result']):
                break
```

I run through df and the list and check for matches.

Output:

```
    No    text reference      result
0  123  60 ABC       ABC            
1  234    1nHG        HG            
2  345   KL HG        FL  wrong item
3  456   21ABC                   ABC
4  567   K 200       200            
5  678   1g HG                    HG
```

The break instruction is important because otherwise a second element could be found within the list and then this second element would overwrite the content in result.

Now I need another solution because the data frame is huge and for loops are inefficient. Think using apply could work but how?

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use ascii borders for DataFrames. Instead just copy the DataFrame as formatted in your shell.

Comment: @Alex - hope that is what you requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating rows, you can iterate your suffixes, which is likely a much smaller iterable. This way, you can take advantage of series-based methods and Boolean indexing.

I've also created an extra series to identify when a row has been updated. The cost of this extra check should be small versus the expense of iterating by row.

```
L = ['ABC', 'HG', 'FL', '200', 'CP1']

df['text'] = df['text'].str.strip()
null = df['reference'].eq('')
df['updated'] = False

for item in L:
    ends = df['text'].str.endswith(item)
    diff = df['reference'].ne(item)

    m1 = ends & null & ~df['updated']
    m2 = ends & diff & ~null & ~df['updated']

    df.loc[m1, 'result'] = item
    df.loc[m2, 'result'] = 'wrong item'

    df.loc[m1 | m2, 'updated'] = True
```

Result:

```
    No    text reference      result updated
0  123  60 ABC       ABC               False
1  234    1nHG        HG               False
2  345   KL HG        FL  wrong item    True
3  456   21ABC                   ABC    True
4  567   K 200       200               False
5  678   1g HG                    HG    True
```

You can drop the final column, but you may find it useful for other purposes.

Comment: Thank you! It is so much faster this way. You do not see a solution where I do not need any for loop right? Because at this point I can not say how many elements my list will carry. So far there are hundreds, but more will follow for sure.

Comment: @MaMo, I can't see anything obvious. Feel free to keep this question open for a while. Someone else might be able to think of a smarter way!